# Windows 7 color schemes

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, download, colors

I'd like to get a pack of color schemes for Windows 7. I've been always using "Rainy day" on Windows XP, which is just 'easier' for the eyes. Since Windows Vista, they stopped shipping the default color schemes. I'd like to use them (again?). Is there a pack? Or a link where to get some? (I really tried to google around, but i failed.)

I use Windows Classic. Why? Because [Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) is:

- Resource hungry (no comment)
- Ugly (one look? Which is just.. eek. Why couldn't they just make some other themes? :/), takes a lot of space (seriously, just look at the title bar how much does it eats.)
- Slow (again, try some [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) hungry stuff and then switch it off (Aero), try it again.). (And it's just sucking all the power out from the battery when I'm without a charger.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any source for color packs, but the colors for window borders are just saved as registry values, which you can edit yourself. Export `HKCU\Control Panel\Colors` from an account on an XP machine with the colors you want, then import that registry file on your windows 7 box. Log out then back in, and it should be set to those colors.

Regarding your defense of Windows Classic though, I must disagree. I used the classic themes on XP almost always, because Luna was, well, hideous. But I'm curious - what kind of graphics card do you have? My computer here has Intel integrated graphics 945GM, the oldest, crappiest integrated graphics chip which runs aero. Everything is completely smooth. Also, they *do* include some themes, quite a few of them in fact. You can change the colors, backgrounds, etc. as you wish. As for battery, that's true, but you can set it to disable transparency when running on battery, which gives much better battery life. I've found that the benefits aero brings far outweigh its supposed ugliness... being able to preview which window I'm switching to, the images on the taskbar, the see-through Alt-Tab, etc. are all quite helpful features, in my opinion.

But anyhow, each to his own. Hopefully that'll help with getting your theme set up the way you'd like... after all, we should each use what we like best, not what some random guy on the internet says he likes ;)

Comment: " we should each use what we like best, not what some random guy on the internet says he likes ;)" Totally agree. That was just my personal opinion. I've got an Intel MHD4500 and a GF9800. Both got some problems when Aero is enabled. Well.. maybe if I'd build an SLI system..beats me. Anyway, for office use (r=1, MSoffice+firefox), Aero is probably really good, I don't see anything wrong if thats the case.) ||
Thanks for the info. I'll try to set it up.

Comment: Hm. Both of those ought to work fine with aero. Did you try updating their graphics drivers to the latest versions? That could make a difference.

Good luck, I hope you get that working successfully!

Comment: Yeah I am using the latest Lenovo and NVidia provided drivers on my machines but it happens on both of them.

Comment: Did the registry thingie from a XP machine exported the key (Rainy Day) which is easier for the eye.

Here it is:
http://pastebin.com/EUaMgcy5

Comment: Glad you got things looking the way you want. I wish I could think of a solution for the aero glitches; sorry.

Comment: Haha no problem. Its not your fault. Guess they are simple Aero bugs or something. Not like it would really matter that much. :) (I would use Aero only on my laptop since I got small screen. BUT. With a small screen, you dont want huge 'frames' which comes with Aero. Vica-versa.

Comment: Aero uses about 200MB video ram, but most benchmarks show little change to actual performance - which is not to say it doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Set of old Windows color scheme HP, converted to Windows 7.
Self extract RAR + opening the settings window color schemes after installation.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4a3f1fwg5p49van/ClassicThemeWin7.exe?dl=0